# DataList equivelant for WP7?

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-7, wrappanel

I'm trying to databind a list of image thumbnails in a grid fashion. In asp.net, I would use something like the DataList and set my repeat columns to 4 or 5. Simple.

I'm going through different controls in the WP7 toolbox and I can't figure out how to do this. I've only been able to bind to a vertical list.

many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WrapPanel : [Article1](http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2010/03/20/Using-the-WrapPanel-from-the-Silverlight-Toolkit-on-Windows-Phone-7.aspx), [Article2](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-WrapPanel-in-depth)

Comment: cool thanks. Only problem is I can't get my data binding to work on this and can't seem to find any examples.

Comment: @senloe: Use `ItemsControl` for data binding and set `WrapPanel` as its `ItemsPanel`.

Comment: Like decyclone said. Also its described in second article.

Comment: thanks guys. Once I figured out the write templates its all coming up. AWESOME!